# Как сделать письмо активации на сайт

Tags: скрипт

Как сделать письмо активации на сайт. Ну типо он вводит мыло и пароль нажимает `Save` и ему должно прийти письмо ссылкой на наш сайт с подтверждением, что все выполнено успешно. Кому не сложно, скиньте что-нибудь на подобие скрипта.

Comment: @oleg73rus73, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 1):

При регистрации генерируешь ключ, который добавляется в ссылку в письме как  $_GET параметр.

Когда пользователь переходит по ссылке, определенный экшен генерирует опять этот ключ и  сравнивается с тем, что в ссылке. Если сгенерированный ключи ключ из URL идентичны - email подтвержден.

Это один из несложных вариантов. Под ключом подразумевается md5 хеш от email + соль